# Using sum function in sql view in oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am trying to create a view using some o group function like sum , avg etc. it is giving error.

```
create view sample_view as 
select A,B,C,D,E, 
       (a + b+c+d+e)/5 as Mean_value, 
       GREATEST(a,b,c,d,e)-LEAST(a,b,c,d,e) as range_value, 
       avg(mean_value)  
from samples;
```

I am getting below error.

```
Error starting at line : 37 in command -
create view sample_view as select A,B,C,D,E, (a + b+c+d+e)/5 as Mean_value, GREATEST(a,b,c,d,e)-LEAST(a,b,c,d,e) as range_value, avg(mean_value)  from samples
Error report -
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Is there anyway to create view in oracle database using group function. I also tried sum() and count(). all those also giving error.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, to clarify your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Root Cause for your problem is:**
You tried to execute a **SELECT** statement that included a GROUP BY function (ie: AVG Function,MIN Function, MAX Function, SUM Function, COUNT Function), but was missing the **GROUP BY** clause.Try to add Group BY clause and run the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - since `avg()` is an aggregate function you can not add this with other columns without adding group by the clause -

```
create view sample_view as 
       select A,B,C,D,E, (a + b+c+d+e)/5 as Mean_value, 
              GREATEST(a,b,c,d,e)-LEAST(a,b,c,d,e) as range_value, 
              avg((a + b+c+d+e)/5) over() 
from samples;
```